# How can I get rid of inactive dead space in submenu popup?

Tags: wpf, popup, styles, contextmenu, menuitem

I have a `ContextMenu` which consists of a number of top level `MenuItem`s, one of which contains a submenu of items bound by `ItemsSource` as follows:

```
<ContextMenu Style="{x:Null}">
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding MenuLabelNewSolution}" Command="New"/>
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding MenuLabelOpenSolution}" Command="Open"/>
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding MenuLabelRecentSolutions}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RecentSolutions, Mode=OneWay}">
        <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Style="{x:Null}" Margin="0" Content="Test"
                        Command="vm:CustomCommands.ExplicitOpen"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding MenuLabelSaveAll}" Command="vm:CustomCommands.SaveAll"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

The submenu items above are test `Button`s to illustrate the issue.

Below, I whittled down the `Style` of the `MenuItem` with expanded columns to illustrate the issue:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Border Style="{x:Null}" Background="LightBlue"
                        BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" />
                        <Popup Style="{x:Null}" Margin="0" 
                               IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                               Placement="Right" VerticalOffset="-3">
                            <StackPanel Style="{x:Null}" Background="Red"
                                        Margin="0" IsItemsHost="True" />
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The issue I am having is that the submenu has a lot of inactive dead space as illustrated by the image below:

[image: Dead Space Menus]

If the user clicks on the dead space in a top level `MenuItem` (which is utilized for icons and gesture text), the menu command is executed.  However, if the user clicks on any of the dead space outside of the test button in a submenu item, the menu command is NOT executed.

What can I do `Style` wise to get rid of the extra space at the submenu level, or at least make the entire submenu region active with respect to the menu command?

Incidentally, if I revert to the default `Style` for `MenuItem`, I still experience the same issue:

[image: Default Menus]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with my `MenuItem` `Style` at all, but because I used a `DataTemplate` for the submenu items.  The following change did the trick:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding MenuLabelNewSolution}" Command="New"/>
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding MenuLabelOpenSolution}" Command="Open"/>
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding MenuLabelRecentSolutions}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RecentSolutions, Mode=OneWay}">
        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="vm:CustomCommands.ExplicitOpen"/>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding MenuLabelSaveAll}" Command="vm:CustomCommands.SaveAll"/>
</ContextMenu>
```